# Orden de declaracion de variables

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y no comprendo el hecho de que si cambio el orden en el que declaro las variables cambia el resultado este es un ejemplo.

Si declaro las Variables en este orden: `X1-X2-V1-V2`
El resultado es otro que si declaro:    `X1-V1-X1-X2`

Por que? gracias, disculpen mi ignorancia .

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kangaroo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int X1=sc.nextInt();
        int V1=sc.nextInt();
        int X2=sc.nextInt();
        int V2=sc.nextInt();

        if(X2>X1 && V2>V1) {
            System.out.println("NO");
        } else {
            while(X2>X1) {
                X2=X2+V2;
                X1=X1+V1;
                if (X1==X2) {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }

                if(X1>X2){
                    System.out.println("NO");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No es el orden en que declares las variables, si no el orden en que introduces los valores.

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask] y tambien hacer el [tour]. Fijate que declaras cada variable al pedir el valor, por lo tanto no estas cambiando el orden de declracion, si no el orden en que pedis los datos, como ya te remarcaron el el comentario anterior

Comment: Con qué datos estás probando? Cómo pruebas la afirmación que estás haciendo?

Comment: Y el problema es...?